# Fried Dough Balls Too Doughy

Tags: dough, dessert, deep-frying

I'm (attempting) to make homemade Cinnamon Dough Balls. However they seem to always come out a little doughy. How can I eliminate this problem? I've tried to poke holes in them but they just get hard. I want them to be cooked but so it's still a little chewy. Any ideas?

The balls are about 1in. to 1 and a half inches in diameter. There is no hard recipe I'm making theses as like an experiment.

Comment: Can you provide a recipe?  Method?  Photos would help...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with experimenting, but then you should provide your experimental proportions.  Did you compare to existing donut recipes, which are plentiful?  How are you cooking?

Comment: if you can't remember proportions, please list ingredients at least.

Comment: None of the clarifying questions have been answered after a considerable period of time.  Voting to close as  unclear since there is no real way to address the issue.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Couldn't it also be a great question that no one seems to have the answer to?

Comment: Judging by the three closing votes, no.  But if you are seeing these comments, why not edit the question to provide more information?

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ It is clear on what I'm asking. Thus the close votes are just because someone started a snowball effect.

Comment: Young Guilo, we will need more information to be able to answer your question. Do you still remember the ingredients/proportions/procedure? And are they too chewy or too doughy? Have you tried cooking them a little bit longer?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably overmixing the batter, which is making the gluten form a "network" and rendering the product chewy. Mix just until there are no streaks of flour remaining.

Try not to roll the dough too much in your hand when forming balls. Instead scoop with a spoon and then lightly form in to a rough sphere.